# Android studio apk signing key changed

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, digital-signature

I devloped an application,and I was maintainting it,updating the apk every few months.
Now lately I reformatted my pc( of course I did a backup of the full project),and installed Android Studio and everything from scartch,and what happend is that I am unable to update my app anymore,because when I build the app on Android Studio and try to install,I'm getting a message that the signature is different from the last app signature,and need to remove the app first.

do i supposed to backup(somehow) the old android studio singing key or something? :(

I always used the default building option,like in the picture below
[image]

Comment: AndroidStudio usually places the app signing key in your home folder in the subdirectory `.android`. The common file name for the keystore is `release.jks`.

Comment: alright,but even if I will locate the current releases.jks file,is that should work?
because the old file,lost on the formatting process..

Comment: Of course you have to locate the keystone in the backup you should have made before formatting your system. If you don't have a backup you are doomed.

Comment: but again,I never used a custom signature to sign my apk,I just used the default android studio signature...never created a custom key.... does Android Studio IDE changes the default signature somewhen...? @Robert

Comment: What "default signature" are you talking about? The path I mentioned is AFIR the default path of the signing key if AS. Not sure if you explicitly have to create it or if it is created without user interaction.

Comment: @Robert you can see in the picture above(in the op) how I build and generate the app
I've never used custom signature only the default Android studio debug signature
I'll try your idea,can you give the full path? I didn't manage to find it...

Comment: The debug key is stored in the same directory just in a different keystone. And I can not give the full path because it is OS and username specific.

Answer (score 0):

Buid -> singned Bundle Apk -> Next -> choose existing

Comment: and than....what?

Comment: then choose  your project file and select your key store